# ASP.net Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a list defined like:

```
var myList = new List<String>();
```

I want to set my web UI DropDownMenu to myList:

```
DropDownMenu = myList;
```

I'm getting the error below, I've tried casting this and not sure how to handle setting a webUI list equal to a List I've manually created.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'

Comment: Try `DropDownMenu.DataSource = myList; DropDownMenu.DataBind();`

Comment: DropDownList is NOT a list, but a control and it uses List<T> as data source.

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you the issue:

```
ASP.net Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'
```

`DropDownList` is a control - it's not a `List<T>`.  What you really want to do is use the `DataSource` property of the `DropDownList`, and set that equal to the `List<T>`, like this:

```
DropDownMenu.DataSource = myList;
```

Then you can call `DataBind()` on the control to bind the list to it:

```
DropDownMenu.DataBind();
```

See [DropDownList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) for more information about the control.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Property `.DataSource` of the UI Control `DropDownMenu`

or

```
dropdownList.Items.AddRange(myList.ToArray());
```

if it has Items Collection.

Comment: There is no `DropDownMenu` control in ASP.NET :)

Comment: Of Course there is Not.. but it seems to be an Object which contains Items collection..